# Is it possible to mute the browser audio from within a Safari Extension?

Tags: xcode, safari, safari-extension, mute

I would like to determine if it is possible to mute the audio coming from the browser in a Safari Extension. For example, I want to programmatically mute the audio every time I went to a specific website.

I know this is possible in a Chrome Extension, though I have looked through the Safari Extension Programming Guide and I can't determine if Apple allows this functionality or not.